# Unit Testing: How to verify that the void method being tested called another method with the correct parameters?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to create a unit test for a message handler that utilizes a void method. The current setup is that once a message is published, another message is sent to an external service and that external service returns a success or failure code. Then depending on the whether the message was a success, a failure, or invalid, a method from another class in the component (Util.java) is called to create an event for logging purposes. Here is the basic set up:

```
public class MessageHandler {

public void OnMessage {

try {

  doSeveralThings{

    code = codeMagicThatDoesntConcernUsCurrently;
  };

   if (code =! "SUCCESS") {
      Util.createEvent(stringVariable, enumStatusObject.ERROR, mapPayload);
      log.info("oh no!")  
      throw new RuntimeException;
   } else {
       Util.createEvent(stringVariable, enumStatusObject.FATAL, mapPayload);
       log.info("It's invalid!")
   }

   catch {
       doStuff()
       Util.createEvent(stringVariable, enumStatusObject.EXCEPTION, mapPayload);
       log.info("Message will be retried.")
    }

   finally {
     Util.createEvent(stringVariable, enumStatusObject.SUCCESS, mapPayload);
       log.info("Yay!")

}

}
```

To test these outcomes, I want to verify that the message handler calls this method (Util.createEvent(stringVariable, enumStatusObject.SUCCESS, mapPayload))
with the correct enumStatusObject based on a mocked "code result".

Things I have tried:

```
@Mock
Util util

verify(util, times(1)).createEvent(anyString(), eq(enumStatusObject.SUCCESS), anyMap());

Mockito.verify(util, times(1)).createEvent(anyString(), eq(enumStatusObject.SUCCESS), anyMap());

Assert.assertTrue(util.createEvent(anyString(), any(enumStatusObject.class), anyMap()).getStatus().equals(enumStatusObject.SUCCESS))
```

I also made an attempt at using ArgumentCaptor from Mockito 2 and had no luck with that.

Is there any way to properly verify this once I call my handler in the test? I am very new to unit testing so I don't know if this is even possible.

the Util.createEvent() method is a static method if that matters. Please advise.

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one from `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods).

Comment: Thank you for the link! I have reviewed a few tutorials so far for Mockito. In this case, I don't want to mock the static method though. I just want to verify that the message handler called the method correctly. I haven't found a way to get around mocking the Util.class, but I don't want to mock the static method with the class itself.

Comment: We want to verify that a static method has been called. Therefore, the static method has to be mocked. We can only `verify(...)` on mocks or spies. And I don't think that we can get a spy on a static method with mockito.

Comment: Ohh. I didn't realize that. I thought that would be considered mocking the actual result and giving myself a false positive or something. I will take a look again at my set up and try mocking the static method as referenced in that article. Good to know about verify and spy, I appreciate that additional information. Thank you!

Comment: The reason you can't verify it like this is because i'm guessing createEvent() method is static and only Mockito 2 can verify static methods. Make the Util class singleton and then have an Util instance in the MessageHandler and  createEvent() non static. Then just mock it.